# Увеличить внутренний контейнер на размер правого отступа родителя

Tags: html, css, адаптивная-верстка

[image: схематично накидал макет]Есть ли способ при такой верстке увеличить размер child на размер правого маргина и сместить его на эту величину вправо. Естественно все резиновое.

```css
.parent {
  max-width: 1170px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    //content
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вариант при помощи JS

```js
function childrenWidth() {
  children = document.querySelector(".children");
  parentWidth = document.querySelector(".parent").offsetWidth;
  marginRigth = (window.innerWidth - parentWidth) / 2;

  children.style.width = parentWidth + marginRigth;
}

childrenWidth();

window.onresize = function() {
  childrenWidth();
};
```

```css
.parent {
  width: 800px;
  margin: auto;
  height: 300px;
  outline: 1px solid black;
}

.children {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="children">

  </div>
</div>
```

Вариант с помощью CSS переменных

```css
:root {
  --parent-width: 800px;
}

.parent {
  width: var(--parent-width);
  margin: auto;
  height: 300px;
  outline: 1px solid black;
}

.children {
  width: calc((100vw - var(--parent-width)) / 2 + var(--parent-width));
  height: 200px;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="children">

  </div>
</div>
```

Вариант без переменных

```css
.parent {
  width: 800px;
  margin: auto;
  height: 300px;
  outline: 1px solid black;
}

.children {
  width: calc((100vw - 100%) / 2 + 100%);
  height: 200px;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="children">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Вариант конечно хороший, но делать это на js по моему немного дико. Я ищу вариант на css, хотя возможно здесь лучше переделать html?...

Comment: @BARS_IK добавил варианты на CSS

Comment: все бы ничего, если бы ширина родителя не была бы: max-width: 1170px;